# java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String on addPreferencesFromResource

Tags: java, android

I have an example about `Preferences` like this:

```
public class UserPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MynewFracment()).commit();
    }
    public static class MynewFracment extends PreferenceFragment{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(saveInstanceStates);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreference);
        }
    }
}
```

But the result return is  `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` on the line `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreferences);` . I really don't know what did I do wrong here?

---

### Update 1

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="PREF_AUTO_UPDATE"
        android:title="Auto refresh"
        android:summary="Select to turn on automatic updateing"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        ></CheckBoxPreference>
    <ListPreference
        android:key="PREF_UPDATE_FREQ"
        android:title="Refresh frequency"
        android:summary="Frequency at which to refresh earthquake list"
        android:entries="@array/update_freq_option"
        android:entryValues="@array/update_freq_values"
        android:dialogTitle="Refresh frequency"
        android:defaultValue="60"
        ></ListPreference>
    <ListPreference
        android:key="PREF_MIN_MAG"
        android:title="Minimum magnitude"
        android:summary="Select the minimum magnitude earthquake to report"
        android:entries="@array/magnitude_options"
        android:entryValues="@array/magnitude"
        android:dialogTitle="Magnitude"
        android:defaultValue="3"
        ></ListPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

---

### Update 2

My R.values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="update_freq_option">
        <item>Every Minutes</item>
        <item>5 mins</item>
        <item>10 mins</item>
        <item>15 mins</item>
        <item>Every Hours</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="magnitude">
        <item>3</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
    </array>

    <string-array name="magnitude_options">
        <item>3</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="update_freq_values">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>15</item>
        <item>60</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

And my stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.begood.earthquake/com.begood.earthquake.UserPreferences}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:205)
                                                                         at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1399)
                                                                         at android.preference.ListPreference.onSetInitialValue(ListPreference.java:278)
                                                                         at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1315)
                                                                         at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1127)
                                                                         at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:156)
                                                                         at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:97)
                                                                         at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:38)
                                                                         at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
                                                                         at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
                                                                         at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
                                                                         at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
                                                                         at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:278)
                                                                         at com.begood.earthquake.UserPreferences$MynewFracment.onCreate(UserPreferences.java:20)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
                                                                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show your `R.xml.userprefrerences`.

Comment: Please show your resources for all the arrays you reference in the preferences XML (such as update_freq_option).

Comment: @NielsMasdorp Updated

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated

Comment: `entryValues` needs to be a `string-array`

Comment: @njzk2 still same error!

Comment: did you ever stored a value for one of those keys? as an int? (try to clear the app data on your device, then run again)

Comment: @njzk2 you are right. That's new for me about clear the app. Please post your answer and explain! Thanks bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the stacktrace, when you call `addPreferencesFromResource`, the prefs are loaded, and `onSetInitialValue` is called to set the value of the pref to whatever was saved before, if at all.

Because it is a `ListPreference`, it uses `getPersistedString`, which tries to load a `String`.

This throws a `ClassCastException` because the pref used to be of an Integer type, and was saved as such.

You know have an existing version of your preferences on the device that is not compatible with the new version of your application.

To solve this, clear the app data, or simply uninstall it.

If you can't do that (if you have users that have the previous version of the app), you need a migration strategy, and probably to change the name of the new preference to avoid conflicts like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to use a string-array for the values as well, even though they are taken to be integers.

```
<string-array name="magnitude">
    <item>3</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="update_freq_values">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>60</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: It still working on my early `Preferences` extends `Activity` with `setContentView`.

Comment: What do you mean? Is this another question?

Comment: No, I have `Preferences extends Activity` and `UserPreferences extends PreferenceActivity` in my project. The `UserPreferences extends PreferenceActivity` was defined in `res/xml` for learning . But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure?  I just copied your code into a test project, saw it fail, then changed to string arrays (all of them), and now it works.

Comment: still same problem with `string-array` bro.

Comment: njzk2  just suggest me about clear the app and it's working fine bro!